# Update config on running ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Spring Boot REST application as a WAR into an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat 8 + Java 8 instance. Subsequently, I realized that I need to configure the following settings (applies to the [Tomcat server.xml](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation)):

```
compression="on"
compressionMinSize="2048"
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/css,..."
```

because `application.properties` in Spring Boot applies only to embedded Tomcat containers. It is too late to change the platform type of the Elastic Beanstalk instance now. Is there any way to update the configuration from the Elastic Beanstalk CLI, using `eb config`? I was looking at this [AWS page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-after.html#configuration-options-after-ebcli), and it looks like it may be possible.

**Updated 01/16/2017**
Thanks to the answer from @dave-maple I started looking in the relevant parts of Elastic Beanstalk documentation.

First, I discovered that Apache is the default proxy server. I could have changed it to nginx, but I didn't have any particular justification to go that route.

Second, I found that adding an `.ebextensions` folder to the top level of my Spring Boot project. I did not want to *pollute* my code base with a cloud provider specific configuration file, but it seemed to be the lowest hanging fruit. So I went for it.

I added the following hierarchy:

```
MySpringBootProject
 |
 +- src
     |
     +- main
         |
         +- resources
             |
             +- ebextensions
                 |
                 +- httpd
                 |   |
                 |   +- conf.d
                 |       |
                 |       +- enable_mod_deflate.conf
                 |
                 +- myapp.config
                 |
                 +- tomcat-settings.config
```

*Contents of* **tomcat-settings.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    GzipCompression: 'true'
```

*Contents of* **myapp.config**

```
container_commands:
05-restart-apache:
    command: "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart"
```

*Contents of* **enable_mod_deflate.conf**

```
# mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Restrict compression to these MIME types
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg

  # Level of compression (Highest 9 - Lowest 1)
  DeflateCompressionLevel 9

  # Netscape 4.x has some problems.
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

  # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

  # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

*Add the following lines to* **pom.xml** (to set up the `.ebextensions` folder in the top level of the generated WAR file):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/ebextensions</directory>
                <targetPath>.ebextensions</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I could have sworn this worked, because I saw the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header... only a couple of times. Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement compression would be at the nginx proxy which runs in front of tomcat. nginx is more efficient at this operation. To do this you can create an [`.ebextensions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) directory in the root of your deployment archive and add an [`nginx-proxy.config`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-platform-configfiles) file such as the following:

**.ebextensions/nginx-proxy.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    GzipCompression: 'true'
    ProxyServer: nginx
```

Then you can build and deploy the new version of your app on Elastic Beanstalk.

If you need to avoid downtime when rolling out the new version you can use a [rolling deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html) (takes instances out of LB before deployment new versions) or even [blue/green deployment (a new environment + cname swap)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html).

**=== EDIT ===**

You may need to customize the `Content-Type` values that nginx will gzip.

To gzip everything, create a config file in .ebextensions:

**.ebextensions/gzip.config**

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf:
    content: |
      gzip_types *;
```

or to be more selective, define the types you want compressed:

**.ebextensions/gzip.config**

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf:
    content: |
      gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml;
```

Comment: Can I apply this configuration change on an instance that has already been set up and is running currently. I can afford an application restart. What I am trying to avoid is adding this to my code base.

Comment: The standard way would be to use .ebextensions (would require an update to your deployment package).

Comment: I did look and I'm not seeing a way to do this with `eb config` or `eb setenv` -- these commands don't seem to support the modification of settings within the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for checking again

Comment: I tried your solution first. I see `Server →nginx/1.10.1` response header but no `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Then I decided to configure the default, Apache proxy server and I have outlined the details of my attempt in my question above. I thought it worked and then again, I don't see the compression response header any more. AWS documentation is not exactly my cup of tea!

Comment: what is the `Content-Type` of the document you're looking to see gzipped?

Comment: `application/json`

Comment: added a description of how to customize `gzip_types`.

Comment: Thanks! The response headers confirm that nginx is the proxy server, but no response compression is taking place even though the response type is `application/json`. I even tried adopting the same folder hierarchy as suggested in [this AWS-EB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-proxy-nginx) page, but to no avail. The mime-types are specified using `gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml;`. The response header includes `Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8` and `Server →nginx/1.10.1`.

Comment: OK. I think I may know what's happening. I'm testing on the default node app and if I log onto the EC2 instance and `curl http://127.0.0.1:8081` (this is what node runs on) the app isn't returning a `Content-Type` header. Setting `gzip_types *;` made it work right away. Try this and LMK if that's working. If it is then all you'd need to do to get a pre-defined list of content-types working is go into your node app and make sure a `Content-Type` header is returned. Link to Node docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Comment: That's incredibly annoying that you can't change the nginx config without redeploying the whole app. For setting up an environment it may take a few trial and errors guesses and if you're having to wait for an upload and redeploy each time it takes it's toll. Is there no config file in the nginx directory that doesn't get overwritten by the redeploy? I might try manually restarting the nginx service for now to test configs.